# Shuffle only rows of multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, shuffle

I am beginner in C++ therefore I am facing problem in shuffling the rows of multidimensional array. I have looked in related solutions but did not helped me much. 
This is what I have tried so far:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    Array<float, 2, 2> f1;
    f1 = allocate(4, 4);
    f1[0][0] = 1.0;
    f1[0][1] = 2.0;
    f1[0][2] = 3.0;
    f1[0][3] = 4.0;

    f1[1][0] = 5.0;
    f1[1][1] = 6.0;
    f1[1][2] = 7.0;
    f1[1][3] = 8.0;

    f1[2][0] = 9.0;
    f1[2][1] = 10.0;
    f1[2][2] = 11.0;
    f1[2][3] = 12.0;

    f1[3][0] = 13.0;
    f1[3][1] = 14.0;
    f1[3][2] = 15.0;
    f1[3][3] = 16.0;

    Array<float,2,2> feature1shuffled = shufflePoints(f1);
    cout<<feature1shuffled<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Array<float,2,2> shufflePoints(Array<float,2,2> dataSet){

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 g(rd());

    shuffle(begin(dataSet), end(dataSet), g);

    return dataSet;
}
```

But it does not shuffles properly based on rows. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You need to call shuffle on each row, not the entire array.  How you do that depends on how you can access the rows in you `Array` class.

Comment: What is `Array` ?

Comment: Probably Eigen::Array

Comment: @Jarod42 I am using this ```Array``` from! [Fertilized](http://www.multimedia-computing.de/fertilized//pages/examples/basic.html) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. It uses a std::array:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, size_t x, size_t y>
using Array = std::array<std::array<T, x>, y>; // use std::array

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::random_device;
using std::mt19937;
using std::begin;
using std::end;

// print array
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<float, 4, 4>& ar)
{
    for(const auto& i : ar) {
        for(const auto& j : i) {
            std::cout << j << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}

Array<float, 4, 4> shufflePoints(Array<float, 4, 4> dataSet){

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 g(rd());

    // this will shuffle the rows but not the elements within them
    shuffle(begin(dataSet), end(dataSet), g);

    return dataSet;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    Array<float, 4, 4> f1{}; // elements set to 0
    //f1 = allocate(4, 4); // not required
    f1[0][0] = 1.0;
    f1[0][1] = 2.0;
    f1[0][2] = 3.0;
    f1[0][3] = 4.0;

    f1[1][0] = 5.0;
    f1[1][1] = 6.0;
    f1[1][2] = 7.0;
    f1[1][3] = 8.0;

    f1[2][0] = 9.0;
    f1[2][1] = 10.0;
    f1[2][2] = 11.0;
    f1[2][3] = 12.0;

    f1[3][0] = 13.0;
    f1[3][1] = 14.0;
    f1[3][2] = 15.0;
    f1[3][3] = 16.0; // Array must have dimensions of 4, 4 to access subscripts [3][3]

    Array<float, 4, 4> feature1shuffled = shufflePoints(f1);
    cout << feature1shuffled << endl;
    return 0;
}
```